# How to rotate a set of 2D points to minimize vertical span in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, rotation, coordinates

I have a collection of 2D points and I want to rotate them so as to display them spanning the **least vertical height**. Is there a way to find the angle *without using optimization*?

As a brief illustration:

```py
import numpy as np

# some initial points spread out vertically
xy = np.random.randn(2, 100)
xy[1, :] *= 2

def rotate(xy, theta):
    """Return a rotated set of points.
    """
    s = np.sin(theta)
    c = np.cos(theta)
    
    xyr = np.empty_like(xy)
    xyr[0, :] = c * xy[0, :] - s *  xy[1, :]
    xyr[1, :] = s * xy[0, :] + c *  xy[1, :]
    
    return xyr

def span(xy):
    """Return the vertical span of the points.
    """
    return xy[1, :].max() - xy[1, :].min()

def plot(xy):
    """2D plot with fixed aspect ratio.
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))
    ax.scatter(*xy, alpha=0.3)
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    plt.show()
    plt.show()
```

Have a look at the original points:

```py
>>> span(xy)
11.503342270923472
>>> plot(xy)
```

[image: Original Points]

Have a look at some rotated points:

```py
>>> xyr = rotate(xy, np.pi / 2)
>>> span(xyr)
4.594620173868735
>>> plot(xyr)
```

[image]

The optimal answer (which should here be around pi / 2) is easy to find by invoking `scipy`:

```py
>>> from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
>>> minimize_scalar(lambda theta: span(rotate(xy, theta)))
     fun: 4.523188831276214
    nfev: 38
     nit: 34
 success: True
       x: 1.590391370976612
```

But surely there is a simpler way that doesn't require scipy - and 38 function evaluations!

Comment: use xyr=np.transpose(xx)

Comment: I'm don't think you will be able to get rid of the optimization. However, if the number of points is larger (for instance `10000` instead of `100`), you may have to consider first extracting the points of the convex hull `hull=xy[:,scipy.spatial.ConvexHull(xy.transpose()).vertices]` and then applying optimization to this subset instead of applying to the whole dataset. This must give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not necessarily optimal, but a good enough simple solution may be to take the main components of the data and rotate the data to align largest main component with the horizontal axis.

```py
import numpy as np

# Posted code...

# Find eigenvector with largest eigenvalue
c = (xy @ xy.T) / (xy.shape[1] - 1)
evals, evecs = np.linalg.eig(c)
imax = np.abs(evals).argmax()
v = evecs[:, imax]
# Correction angle is opposite of vector angle
theta = -np.arctan2(v[1], v[0])
# Rotate
xy2 = rotate(xy, theta)
# Plot
plot(xy2)
```

Output:

[image: Result]

Comment: This is definitely useful and the kinda thing I was looking for! Though for some data (e.g. a square ``xy = np.random.uniform(size=(2, 1000)``) which have more than one 'large direction' it will produce a vertical span pretty close to the maximum.

Comment: @jawknee Yes, that's true, this works mostly for "rounded" data that is more or less compact. I don't know how it would work for multimodal distributions of data either.